# Is handoff available for Safari with Yosemite and iOS8.02?

Tags: iphone, ios, macbook-pro, continuity

**Assumptions:**

- Yosemite installed on a Macbook Pro Retina
- iOS 8.02 installed on an iPhone 6

I was able to receive a call on my iPhone and have the handoff of the call to my Macbook Pro work successfully.

[This article](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-set-up-and-use-handoff-in-yosemite-and-ios-8-1646745583) suggests that handoff is available for Safari.

[image]

On the home screen it should look like this:

[image]

I can't see either of these icons popping up - even though I can get handoff for calls working.

My question is: **Is handoff available for Safari with Yosemite and iOS8.02?**

Comment: Why are you asking about Safari when your screen shows Chrome?

Comment: I asked because that was the screenshot from the linked article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes handoff is available for Safari in Yosemite and iOS 8.02, I just tested it. But it does not work with Google Chrome as shown in the screenshot (at least not yet and in my case).

But you can use iCloud tabs on your iPhone. It shows you which tabs are opened on other devices, have a look a this [page](http://www.imore.com/how-access-icloud-tabs-iphone-ios-7). It is for iOS7 but it works the same in iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I got it working. There were a couple of steps:

1. Log out and log in to iCloud on both machines
2. Ensure that 'Safari' is checked in the iCloud System Preferences

After this the Chrome icon popped up on my Mac when browsing in safari on the iphone. (Chrome is the default browser on the mac)

I also got the safari icon on the iphone lock screen when browsing in Safari on my mac.